# "Base table or view not found" error after "composer dump-autoload"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, composer-php

I'm developing site with Laravel. I ran `composer dump-autoload`, It occured something error messages, but I did not look at it.

After that, I had post on the current site, but db error occured.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'testdb.articles_e' (SQL: select articles_e.*, (select count(id) from votes_e where votes_e.article_id=articles_e.id and votes_e.up!=0) as up, `articles`.*, `article_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id`, `article_tag`.`article_id` as `pivot_article_id` from `articles` inner join `article_tag` on `articles`.`id` = `article_tag`.`article_id` where `article_tag`.`tag_id` = 9 and `h` = 0 order by `id` desc, `created_at` desc limit 32 offset 0)
```

composer.json is this.

```
composer.json
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "erusev/parsedown-extra": "0.7.1",
    "laracasts/flash": "*.*.*",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": ["app/helpers.php"]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
}
```

'articles_e' is a table that is not currently used. I've deleted and re-created the 'articles_e' table, but that does not solve.
Also, since I first created the migration and created the db, I changed the table structure in mysql several times directly. I do not know if this is the reason.

thanks for your help. thanks.

Comment: does your .env file have the proper credentials?

Comment: I think the env file is fine. Until the problem occurred, the writing worked well.

Comment: if you're database is for development use then remove all the tables from the database and run php artisan db:migrate again

Comment: Is there any other solution? I want to avoid that if possible because there is a modified structure directly in mysql.

Comment: share the migration code for articles_e

Comment: migration code for "articles_e" is not exist. That table was created directly in mysql.

Comment: sorry I don't know any other alternative besides php artisan migrate:rollback

Comment: Maybe you have used this table in relations

Comment: Search for `articles_e` in your whole project to find out where is being called.